# Android Search in Data

Tags: sql, android

At the moment I want to have three columns in my database for Notes:

```
ID | Title | Content
```

The table could have a few hundred entries.
I want to be able to search for parts of the content. When `Content` is "this is a test sentence" and the user searches for "test" or even "te" then the row should be displayed.
Is it okay to store this information in an SQLlite3 database or is there a way to have better performance?

Comment: How frequently your data/content does change?

Comment: @Pentium: It depends a bit on the user behavior but I expect it to not change much but rather stay constant.
I'm okay with slow updates of content when I get fast search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Databases are fine for this stuff, just make sure you use indexes and, if you can avoid usage of `LIKE` open on both edges

   wrong, it does **not** use indexes

   where data like '%search%'

   **good, it uses indexes**

   where data like 'search%'
2. If you will have records counting over million, or long texts. You could break time in categories, and store them in different tables. This way you will tell the user to search in that category only.
3. Make sure that you implement the right on text change event + key timer, as you can end up to issue db requests for a search too soon, and the user has not finished typing.

In mobile/desktop environment a 300ms wait for next keypress is advised.

To explain what I mean: suppose you want to searc for "blueray"

- user types in "b" on text change fires, search is requested with like 'b%'
- user types in "l" on text change fires, search is requested with like 'bl%'
- user types in "u" on text change fires, search is requested with like 'blu%'

you will end up doing inefficient queries, that take long-long time

you should do:

- user types in "b", you should wait for 300ms for next key
- user types in "l", you should wait for 300ms for next key
- user types in "u", text reached length 3, allow the search

Comment: If I want to find a sentence like "The blueray is really awesome", don't I have to use %blu% or should I somehow create an extra table that lists all words in all tables?

Comment: In this case you need like open on both sides. If I were you I would do a quick research on the device to see how it performs with 100k records. Suppose it's slow with 10k entries too, then you need to split your content based on categories, and allow search on restricted records.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK to store the information on SQLite3. The SQL will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Content LIKE '%test%'
```

Comment: How's the performance of such a query? How long does it take for 1000 entries with long Strings?
Is the performance acceptable?

Comment: 1000 entries is fine, problem raises when it reaches 50k. It depends by the mobile device too.